# Fill only last among of consecutive NaN in Pandas by mean of previous and next valid values

Tags: pandas, interpolation, nan, missing-data, imputation

Fill only last among of consecutive NaN in Pandas by mean of previous and next valid values. If one NaN, then fill with mean of next and previous. If two consecutive NaN, impute second one with mean of next and previous valid values.

Series:

[image]

expected output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is remove consecutive missing values without last, then use `interpolate` and assign back last missing value by condition:

```
m =  df['header'].isna()
mask = m & ~m.shift(-1, fill_value=False)

df.loc[mask, 'header'] = df.loc[mask | ~m, 'header'].interpolate()
print (df)
    header
0     10.0
1     20.0
2     20.0
3     20.0
4     30.0
5      NaN
6     35.0
7     40.0
8     10.0
9      NaN
10     NaN
11    30.0
12    50.0
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.assign(m=m, mask=mask))
    header      m   mask
0     10.0  False  False
1     20.0  False  False
2     20.0   True   True
3     20.0  False  False
4     30.0  False  False
5      NaN   True  False
6     35.0   True   True
7     40.0  False  False
8     10.0  False  False
9      NaN   True  False
10     NaN   True  False
11    30.0   True   True
12    50.0  False  False


print (df.loc[mask | ~m, 'header'])
0     10.0
1     20.0
2      NaN
3     20.0
4     30.0
6      NaN
7     40.0
8     10.0
11     NaN
12    50.0
Name: header, dtype: float64
```

Solution for interpolate per groups is:

```
df.loc[mask, 'header'] = df.loc[mask | ~m, 'header'].groupby(df['groups'])
                                                    .transform(lambda x: x.interpolate())
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael . This works beautifully for a series which is the original question. Any pointers to how it can be applied to within groups? Let's say if the index were 'AA', 'AA','AA', 'AA','AB','AB','AB','AC','AC','AC' ? If I wish to replace the values only within each groups? I see that isna() doesn't work on groupby object.

Comment: @SubhojyotiLahiri - Then use `df.loc[mask, 'header'] = df.loc[mask | ~m, 'header'].groupby(df['groups']).transform(lambda x: x.interpolate())`

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
s = df['header']
m = s.isna()
df['header'] = s.ffill().add(s.bfill()).div(2).mask(m&m.shift(-1, fill_value=False))
```

output and intermediates:

```
    header  output  ffill  bfill      m  m&m.shift(-1)
0     10.0    10.0   10.0   10.0  False          False
1     20.0    20.0   20.0   20.0  False          False
2      NaN    20.0   20.0   20.0   True          False
3     20.0    20.0   20.0   20.0  False          False
4     30.0    30.0   30.0   30.0  False          False
5      NaN     NaN   30.0   40.0   True           True
6      NaN    35.0   30.0   40.0   True          False
7     40.0    40.0   40.0   40.0  False          False
8     10.0    10.0   10.0   10.0  False          False
9      NaN     NaN   10.0   50.0   True           True
10     NaN     NaN   10.0   50.0   True           True
11     NaN    30.0   10.0   50.0   True          False
12    50.0    50.0   50.0   50.0  False          False
```